# socket.io sending hyperlink text

Tags: hyperlink, socket.io

I have a basic socket.io realtime chat application. The client side when receiving a message:

```
socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
```

When I send a URL in the message, it isn't hyperlinked. Does anyone know how to get the URL portion of the message hyperlinked?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
KW

Comment: Simply priting a text containing url would not automatically hyperlink the url part. For that you would have to use filters on the text to detect urls and replace url part with anchor tags.
For that either you could write your own filters or use some libraries.  Lots of libraries are available for just that.

Comment: Thanks Nijeesh! I tried sending a text with anchor tags but it is displaying the anchor tag literally, not hyperlinking it.